# How do I get the discount price for promo code or gift card?

Tags: magento

I am trying to get the discount that is being calculated in the cart. I can get the coupon code with this: `Mage::getSingleton('checkout/cart')->getQuote()->getCouponCode();`
But I have yet to figure out how to get the amount that is discounted from the coupon code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
  // get coupon amount 
   $quote = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->getQuote();

    foreach ($quote->getAllItems() as $item){

    echo $item->getDiscountAmount();

    } 
   // get giftcard amount
   $giftcard = $quote->getGiftCardsAmountUsed();
```

Comment: hey i tried this.. but the gift card amount is empty.. any idea why that might be the case?

Comment: Hi! Did you find out how to get amount applied?